# Motion activated shutter built in to Olympus cameras?

Tags: olympus, triggers, olympus-omd

I have been reading the manuals for the Olympus OM-D II and have not found any feature that allows for motion triggering the shutter. By "motion triggering" I mean situations where I would want to film an animal entering or leaving its burrow, for example, so the camera would be setup and when the animal arrived, the camera would begin filming (or shooting).

Does the camera have this ability, or do I need to use a separate accessory?

Comment: Which OM-D Mark II? The E-M1 mkII, E-M5 mkII, or E-M10 mkII?

Answer (score 3):

The camera does not have this ability. You will need a separate motion trigger, sometimes called lightning triggers. Many of the available triggers can also be triggered by loud sounds.

Some of the triggers currently available:

- [Ubertronix Strike Finder](https://strikefinder.photo/strike-finder-store/) line of triggers
- [Pluto Trigger](https://plutotrigger.com/products/pluto-trigger)
- [Vello FreeWave Stryker](http://www.vellogear.com/camera-accessories/camera-trigger-systems) line of triggers
- [MIOPS Smart Trigger](http://miops.com)
- [Opteka LTX80-O Trigger](http://opteka.com/ltx80o.aspx)
- [MK Controls Lightning Bug](http://www.mkcontrols.com/lightningbug/)